# Unable to run an Angular UI in Play app using IntelliJ

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I want to create a `Play` application which uses Angular UI in IntelliJ. This has been done (https://github.com/lbialy/play-ng2-webpack2) so I suppose it is possible.

First I created Play2 App using IntelliJ in `web` folder
Then I created an Angular app using Angular CLI in `ui` folder inside `web` folder
Then I ran `ng build` in `ui` folder. This created a `dist` folder 
I copied the contents of `dist` folder in `web/public/ui`
Then I changed the `index.scala.html` to follows to use the Angular UI.

```
@(message: String)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@message</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/common/css-reset.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/common/common-styles.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css")">

    </head>
    <body class="body-common-styles">
        <div class="css-grid-container-common-styles">
            <app-root></app-root>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/inline.bundle.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/polyfills.bundle.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/styles.bundle.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/vendor.bundle.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/main.bundle.js")"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I do not see the `app-root` UI (the default UI which Angular CLI creates) at `localhost:9000`. I see the blue background which my css creates but none of the Angular stuff.

If I run `ng serve` in `web/ui` then I see the Angular stuff at `localhost:4200`.

What am I doing wrong? I suppose that if `js` files are available in public folder then I should be able to access them in index.scala.html (which I suppose I am able to as I do not see any 404 messages in browser developer console).

Update
Though I dont see 404 errors,I see following errors in developer console but I am not sure if they are Angular related (there are loads of `font` errors!).

```
addStyles.js:115 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

insertStyleElement @ addStyles.js:115
createStyleElement @ addStyles.js:132
addStyle @ addStyles.js:165
addStylesToDom @ addStyles.js:77
webpackJsonp.../../../../style-loader/addStyles.js.module.exports @ addStyles.js:37
../../../../../src/styles.css @ styles.css?043a:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 339cf76f3ca05ce50b1e:54
2 @ addStyles.js:246
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 339cf76f3ca05ce50b1e:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 339cf76f3ca05ce50b1e:25
(anonymous) @ styles.bundle.js:1
addStyles.js:225 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-xylbkVtqJQuRDTD/O50Zkbb0PJR006+vxsulnu5EOD4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

applyToTag @ addStyles.js:225
addStyle @ addStyles.js:172
addStylesToDom @ addStyles.js:77
webpackJsonp.../../../../style-loader/addStyles.js.module.exports @ addStyles.js:37
../../../../../src/styles.css @ styles.css?043a:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 339cf76f3ca05ce50b1e:54
2 @ addStyles.js:246
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 339cf76f3ca05ce50b1e:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 339cf76f3ca05ce50b1e:25
(anonymous) @ styles.bundle.js:1
localhost/:1 Refused to load the font '
localhost/:1 Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAIw4ABEAAAABQcAAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHUE9TAAABgAAACU8AABMOD1XXMEdTVUIAAArQAAAAUwAAAHCOOI56T1MvMgAACyQAAABbAAAAYNrnrZBjbWFwAAALgAAAAIEAAAC0jBiQAGN2dCAAAAwEAAAAKgAAAC4HyBmgZnBnbQAADDAAAAOBAAAG5XJackBnYXNwAAAPtAAAAAwAAAAMAA0AGGdseWYAAA/AAABViQAAvQzAr6AGaGVhZAAAZUwAAAA2AAAANvzd8kdoaGVhAABlhAAAAB8AAAAkD/YHpGhtdHgAAGWkAAACFAAAA26BW0HVa2VybgAAZ7gAAB/3AABeRKoEucNsb2NhAACHsAAAAb4AAAG+1eip6m1heHAAAIlwAAAAIAAAACAByAf2bmFtZQAAiZAAAADEAAABYBoFNRJwb3N0AACKVAAAAZYAAAJBVvgNXnByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

compiler.js:34062 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".


    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at evalExpression (compiler.js:34062)
    at jitStatements (compiler.js:34080)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._interpretOrJit (compiler.js:34663)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34591)
    at compiler.js:34490
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34490)
    at compiler.js:34360
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
```

Comment: check the console for errors and update to the post

Comment: added errors I am seeing in developer console but I am not sure whether they are related to Angular

Comment: I installed Augury and noticed this message in developer console - `This application is not an Angular application. This application cannot be inspected using Augury.` I wonder why this is not an angular app when I have copied all the required 'js' in public folder. What is the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the creator of repository you mentioned (which I probably should update to latest angular and play by the way). It surely is possible to integrate angular and play of course and you are on the right track! Actually the glue code in my repository does exactly the same thing you are doing - I let sbt build angular by calling ng build (so that it yields dist directory) and then tell it to move files from dist to play's public directory. Second thing my glue code is doing is that it integrates Angular's protractor-based e2e testing harness into Play's tests, so that `sbt test` tests ng app along with backend. I haven't updated it lately and as a result clone of my repo won't build without some fixes.

The errors you are seeing are related to default Content Security Policy used by Play Framework. From what I'm seeing angular is trying to fetch content from sources other than the same host and your `default-src` policy is set to `self`. You should probably either whitelist trusted content sources or modify your build to pull everything from web and into your `dist` directory, so that you don't have to fetch anything from hosts other than yours (that's the safer solution, but you don't want to do this in most cases).

Here's some reading about [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and [Play's CSP configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders)

Comment: Firstly, many thanks. I can now run the application. However, I am not sure if the approach I took is correct. I had to set `contentSecurityPolicy = null` in `application.conf` which I suppose is not ideal. I'll do more research to find 1) which other sources Angular (or my app) is trying to connect to (and is getting blocked) 2) How to pull everything from web into `dist` directory.

Comment: I have created this another SO question related to the font issue I am facing. Could it be that I need to put `node_modules` in public folder as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409071/i-get-font-load-error-but-i-am-not-explicitly-using-a-font-from-the-web-how-cou