# several font related and Uncaught Eval error

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I am getting several errors related to font/style and one `uncaught eval`. Pic attached. My Angular app isn't working and I am wondering if it could be due to these errors. However, I do not understand the meaning and implications of these. What do these errors mean, what harm do they cause and how to solve them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ahead of time(AOT) compilation while ng serve. try ng serve with following command

```
ng serve --aot
```

Comment: I dont want to use ng serve. Could I use aot with build?

Comment: @ManuChadha yes. you can use with build also .

Comment: Actually my main problem is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350801/unable-to-run-an-angular-ui-in-play-app-using-intellij. Thus I cannot use ng serve as i want to deploy my angular ui using play framework.

Comment: I think you are using eval in your code. Angular by default does not work in strict Content security policy (CSP). You need to add Content-Security-Policy header in your server response. Check official link here : https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy

Comment: Thanks. `contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"` worked.